# set default text in text area in ionic 2 . The default value is from rest api

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How to set default text in text area in ionic 2 . The default value is from rest api, my code is

```
 messageDraftList = {

  "status": " ",
  "message": " ",
  "draft_mail": [{ }],

};

getMessageDraftData() {
if (this.networkcheck.online == true) {
  this.dmessage.getMessageDraftData(this.uid).subscribe( data => {

   this.messageDraftList = data;
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let message of messageDraftList.draft_mail">
    <div *ngIf=condition>
      <ion-label>Subject</ion-label>
      <ion-input class="options" value="{{message.subject}}" [(ngModel)]="messageData.subject"  style="background-color:white"> {{message.subject}}</ion-input>

      <ion-label>Content

      </ion-label>
      <ion-textarea  rows="4" class="text" value="{{message.content}}" [(ngModel)]="messageData.content"  style="background-color:white"> {{message.content}}</ion-textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It shows nothing 
thanks in advance

Comment: What does a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.messageDraftList)` show in the subscribe?

Comment: it shows {status: "on", message: " ready", draft_mail: Array(8)}

Comment: Alright so I suppose your code is just fine but you're setting the list wrong. Instead of `this.messageDraftList = data` try setting `this.messageDraftList = data.draft_mail`

Comment: i tried but this also not working

Comment: Alright, what does the console.log print now?

Comment: it shows {Array(8)}

Comment: Then this is probably a server side issue and not a client side problem. In your response to your call you get the *String* value of `Array(8)` instead of the Array object containing 8 objects. Please post your server side code cause I suppose you're returning a `.toString()` or something instead of the JSON stringified objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found a solution 
 in ts file

just add

`messageData.subject="values to be displayed"`